# A task was canceled Xamarin Exception

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting a "**A task was canceled exception**" in my **PostAsync**. What is the cause of this? How can I fix this? I research the possible cause they think it is because of a timeout. If so, how can I extend the timeout time? If not, what are the possible fix for this?

```
try
{
    string url = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Request=Fsq6Tr";
    string contentType = "application/json";
    JObject json = new JObject
    {
        { "CAF", caf },
        { "CustomerID", retailerCode },
        { "EmployeeNumber", employeeNumber },
        { "Street", street },
        { "Barangay", barangay },
        { "Town", town },
        { "District", district },
        { "Province", province },
        { "Country", country },
        { "Landmark", landmark },
        { "Telephone1", telephone1 },
        { "Telephone2", telephone2 },
        { "Mobile", mobile },
        { "Email", email },
        { "Location", location },
        { "Date", Convert.ToDateTime(date) },
        { "StartTime", Convert.ToDateTime(startTime) },
        { "EndTime", Convert.ToDateTime(endTime) },
        { "Photo1", photo1 },
        { "Photo2", photo2 },
        { "Photo3", photo3 },
        { "Video", video },
        { "MobilePhoto1", photo1url },
        { "MobilePhoto2", photo2url },
        { "MobilePhoto3", photo3url },
        { "MobileVideo", videourl },
        { "Rekorida", rekorida },
        { "Merchandizing", merchandizing },
        { "TradeCheck", tradecheck },
        { "Others", others },
        { "OtherConcern", otherconcern },
        { "Remarks", remarks },
        { "LastSync", Convert.ToDateTime(current_datetime) },
        { "MobileUpdate", Convert.ToDateTime(current_datetime) }
   };

   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));

    await DisplayAlert("Success!", "Form sent successfully!", "Got it");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
         await DisplayAlert(" Sending Error ", ex.Message, "Got it");
   }
```

Comment: How and where is this code invoked?

Comment: Which OS are you using? iOS?

Comment: @SushiHangover Android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, oddly HttpClient throws a TaskCancelledException for request timeouts. Here's a good blog post on timeouts with HttpClient: https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/

HttpClient does have a Timeout property that you can set: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

To set the timeout for all requests that use that HttpClient:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(200); // this is double the default
```

That said, it would be good to find out why your request is taking more than 100 seconds to complete. Bad network? Server overworked and responding slowly? There are many reasons why a web request might be slow.

Comment: the request is taking more than 100 seconds because I am send a Base64 string to my server

Comment: OK, but if I answered your question, which was "how can I extend the timeout time?", please accept the answer as I showed you how to extend the Timeout time, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

My timeout reason was because device had **energy saving mode** and it **blocks background connections**. Maybe it could help someone...